# Using random numbers to generate # of events given an expected average # of events

Tags: probability

Let's say a galaxy creates 3 stars every year on average, but it's possible for it to create 0 stars during a year or up to, let's say, 10000 stars. Using randomly generated numbers in a program I want to do the following, but can't quite figure it out:

1. For every year that passes, I want to randomly generate how many stars the galaxy created, such that on average it creates 3, but could create anywhere from 0-10000 depending on the randomly generated value
2. Scale it down so that if only one day passes, then how many stars are created that day given the randomly generated value

I'm imagining I need to come up with some sort of distribution that accepts a random number as an input and gives me a number of events as an output, but I'm not quite sure how to do this or if this is the correct approach. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One possibility is to model the number of stars created in any given year as having a Poisson distribution with parameter $r = 3 t$ where $t = 1$.
2. Use $t = 1/365$ to obtain the distribution for any given day.

John D. Cook has a blog post on [Generating Poisson random values](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/14/generating-poisson-random-values/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So from what I understand, there is no upper bound to the number that this Poisson random number generator could produce? This isn't a problem, by the way, I actually prefer this, but I just want to clarify.

Comment: There is no upper bound for a Poisson random variable *in theory*. However, any *implementation* will have an upper bound (though it will be much larger than 10,000).

Comment: Perfect, thanks again.